# Regular Expression - Reverse Pattern Searching

Tags: regex, search, replace, vi

Is there a way using regular expression to find all " that doesn't match multiple patterns.

Example:
"I'm having a hard time"|"getting this "match" to"|10|"work"

Basically I want to replace the quotes that doesn't match ^" "| |" or "$
So in this scenario it would only replace the quotes around "match"

In this particular case, I'm attempting to us VI to do this.

Thanks for any suggestions you can provide.

Comment: What language to you want your regex to work with? Some allow look behinds, others don't. For python you could use: r'(?<=\W)\d+(?=\W)'

Comment: I'm attempting to use VI or some editor that supports regular expression such as Notepad++

Comment: Try my code with the look behind then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using negative lookbehind and negative lookahead:

```
:%s/[$|]\@<!\"[\^|]\@!//gc
```

**Edit:** I changed my approach. Is the following regex sufficient?

```
:%s/\([^\^|]\)\"\([^$|]\)/\1\2/g
```

Comment: Couldn't get that to work, passed error checking but didn't change the values.

Comment: I updated my regex and it is almost working for me now. I cannot quite figure out how to stop it from matching quotes at the start or end of a line.

Comment: Awesome, this was really helpful.  I was attempting to swap " for ' so I just had to add a ' between \1'\2

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use this Javascript line:

```
str = str.replace(/ \"match\" /g, 'match');
```

**EDIT:**

```
function replaceSentence(mySentence, secondSentence)
{
    str = str.replace(/ mySentence /g, secondSentence);
}
```

And the example would be like this:

```
replaceSentence("match", match);
```

Comment: "match" is just an example.  in my case it could be a multitude of words or none at all between the quotes.